# At the end of a CSS -webkit-transform: translate the image flashes or flickers

Tags: css, css-transitions, android-browser, translate-animation

When I test a `-webkit-transform: translate(500px ,0)` it does it smooth enough, but once it's finished the img it was moving flashes or flickers. I tested in an Android browser.

Is there any way to get rid of this flashing?

Im trying to replicate the top banner in the Android Market app (on a tablet). It appears that it's all done with HTML/CSS by the way it loads.

Answer (score 2):

-webkit-backface-visibility should your problem, but to ensure that performance is optimal on ALL devices, cache the DOM and use translate3d as it is GPU accelerated.

This is a great source that can help you improve performance on all devices.

[Improving Performance of HTML5 App](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/)

UPDATE

translate3d and other 3d properties are no longer hardware accelerated on Mac OS X Mountain Lion or iOS 6+, beware.